# I can't figure out how to loop twice in a Function to modify a list

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lst2 =[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
                           
def even(fn,sn):
    for i in sn:
        if i %2 == 0:
         fn.append(i)  # from this point i get this output for lst: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,16,18,20]



even(lst,lst2)
print(lst)
```

What I am trying to do here is take lst2 even numbers add them to lst, then modifying lst into all even numbers. Keep in mind I am trying to do all this in ONE function. if anyone can help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated.
my desire output for lst is [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]

Comment: `list(filter(lambda i: i % 2 == 0, lst + lst2))` ?

Comment: @rv.kvetch They want to modify `lst` in place in the function.

Comment: I suspect they may not @Barmar, I have a feeling OP is not aware of the difference, as they haven't explicitly said anything about modifying the list in place. I think the word "modify" is being used informally here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a slice assignment to replace a list with a modified list.

```
def even(fn, sn):
    fn.extend(sn)
    fn[:] = [x for x in fn if x % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: or even just one line: `fn[:] = [x for x in fn + sn if x % 2 == 0]`

Comment: thanks! that's exactly what i was trying to figure out!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this. Traverse over `lst` in reverse order, so that we can also remove from the list while iterating over it.

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
lst2 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]


def even(fn, sn):
    # Add all elements of second list to the first list
    fn.extend(sn)

    for i in range(len(fn) -1, -1, -1):
        if fn[i] % 2 != 0:
            fn.pop(i)


even(lst, lst2)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my sugestion:

```
def even(fn,sn):
    union = fn + sn
    return [i for i in union if i % 2 == 0]
```

With the sum operation you can append all the list "sn" in the final of the list "fn". Then you can consctruct a list with only the even numbers.

I used a list comprehension that make a for loop in one line.

Comment: The function is supposed to modify `fn` in place.